# Power BI Measure is showing URL instead of image

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure which is looking at the value of the ID in one table and fetching an image URL from another table based on this same ID and a specific category:

```
Shiny = 
VAR pokemonVariant = SELECTEDVALUE( Pokemon[ID] )

RETURN
    IF(
        NOT ISBLANK( pokemonVariant ),
        CALCULATE( 
            SELECTEDVALUE( 'Variants'[Url] ), 
            FILTER( 'Variants', 'Variants'[ID] = pokemonVariant && 'Variants'[Variant] = "Shiny" )
        )
    )
```

It returns the correct url, however I don't want it to be a URL, I want it to display the actual image. It seems that measures are converting image URLs to text.

How can I change the result to be an Image URL as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your measure in the `Fields` pane, then from `Measure tools` -> `Properties` change `Data category` to be `Image URL`:

[image]

Also take a look at [Display images in a table, matrix, or slicer in a report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/power-bi-images-tables) article.